# SSRS URL Encode

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have an issue with an expression in SSRS

**Project**

> USE SSRS Expressions and custom code to encrypt, and then determine
>   target to hyperlink to based on environment.

**What we have accomplished**

> We have created a custom DLL using a custom library imported into the
>   References in Report properties
>
> From within the Expression then we wrote Switch statement to determine
>   the target as follows:

Expression

```
=Switch
(
Globals.ReportServerUrl = "https://devportal2.xxx.com/sites/Co" , "https://stage.connect.com/secure/clr/er=" & Code.EncryptRin(Fields!Member_Member_ID_.Value),
Globals.ReportServerUrl = "https://testportal2.xxx.com/sites/Co" , "https://stage.connect.com/secure/clr/er=" & Code.EncryptRin(Fields!Member_Member_ID_.Value),
Globals.ReportServerUrl = "https://stageportal2.xxx.com/sites/Co" , "https://www.connect.com/secure/clr/er=" & Code.EncryptRin(Fields!Member_Member_ID_.Value),
Globals.ReportServerUrl = "https://stageportal2.xxx.com/sites/Co" , "https://www.connect.com/secure/clr/er=" &
 Code.EncryptRin(Fields!Member_Member_ID_.Value),true, "https://stage.connect.com/secure/clr/er=" + Code.EncryptRin(Fields!Member_Member_ID_.Value)
)
```

Custom Code

```
Public Function UserName()
Try
    Return Report.User!UserID
  Catch
    Return "System"
  End Try
End Function


Public Function EncryptRin(ByVal Rin as string) As String
    Return Encryption.AESConsole.EncryptText(Rin)
End Function
```

In the above there are two functions one is not relevant and that's the Username() one. The second one is the part we need to encode.

**What I need help with**

We need to encode the encrypted portion of the URL before we can send it over. But I'm a little confused on WHERE this needs to happen.

So my understanding is I need to do this from the Expression because that's where we are referencing it. If that's not where it happens, what would the syntax look like to reference a parameter in the above function before it gets to the expression?

Has anyone done this? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue? It looks like it should be working. Your encrypted **MemberID** is being added to which ever URL is used in the **Expression** with the**SWITCH**.

Comment: I need to encode the string before it gets encrypted. @HannoverFist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.net you should be able to use [`System.Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encode the data before encrypting it. Something like this:

```
Public Function EncryptRin(ByVal Rin as string) As String
    Return Encryption.AESConsole.EncryptText(Uri.EscapeDataString(Rin))
End Function
```